# Delete crashes reports using Terminal

Tags: terminal, crash, macos, plist

I am trying delete the crashing reports plist using terminal (OS Sierra):

```
sudo rm -rf "~/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/*"
```

But nothing happen. What I am doing bad?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde expansion must not be quoted nor the wildcard. The space between Application and Support would be quoted with a backslash.

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/*
```